# Plotting the following spin chain of atoms

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I want to plot one dimensional chain of atoms and interactions between them as shown similar to shown in following two figure. Any suggestions or help ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about what exactly you want to plot?

Comment: @DanielHuber, I want to plot figures similar to shown above . what else is required ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) with custom [`VertexShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShapeFunction.html) and [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html) as follows:

```
vertexlist = Range[10];

relation = 1 <= Abs[#2 - #] <= 2 &;

vertexCoordinates = Thread[{vertexlist, 0}];

vSF = Inset[Graphics3D[{Green, Specularity[White, 10], Sphere[]}, 
     Boxed -> False], #, Center, Scaled[.3]] &;

eSF = GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", 
      "Curvature" -> If[OddQ@#2[[1]], 1, -1] (Abs[Subtract @@ #2] - 1)}][##] &;

edgeLabelingRule = {UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; b - a == 2 && OddQ[a] :>
     Placed[Subscript[J, 1], {1/2, {0, -2}}]};

RelationGraph[relation, vertexlist, 
 VertexCoordinates -> vertexCoordinates, 
 EdgeLabels -> edgeLabelingRule,
 VertexShapeFunction -> vSF,
 EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: You are wonderful, thank you very much